# Why does browser freeze in AngularJS controller method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the FireFox developer tools open, and the debugger has break points at every line in a function that handles form input.  The debugger indicates that execution of the method simply breaks at one specific line without any explanation.  The code is running, needing confirmation at each step, and then all of the sudden the method stops executing at a specific line, leaving the user's view in a static state.  There is no longer any ability to click continue in the debugger or to view any parameter values because the code simply stops running and exits, leaving the user hanging without response.

What specific changes do I need to make to the code below to get the method to continue running? How can I determine what the problem is so that I know what conditions the code needs to handle?  Phantom halting of program execution at arbitrary points is disconcerting.  If this were Java, the ide would tell me what the problem is.

At first, this line of code was causing the problem:

```
$scope.resultmessage.webleadid = $scope.wleadid;
```

But then I created an if test to stop that line from being read, and the result was that the very next line caused the same problem:

```
$scope.resultmessage.name = $scope.uname;
```

Here is the method in the AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.pinForm = function(isValid) {
    console.log("inside pinForm")
    if (isValid) {
        console.log("pinForm is Valid!")
        if($scope.existing !='yes'){$scope.resultmessage.webleadid = $scope.wleadid;}
        $scope.resultmessage.name = $scope.uname;
        $scope.resultmessage.existing = $scope.existing;
        var funcJSON = $scope.resultmessage;
        auth.authenticate2(funcJSON, function(authenticated2) {
            if (authenticated2=='yes') {
                $scope.processStep="done";
                console.log(auth.authenticated2);
                $location.path('/secure');
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });

    }
};
```

And here is the code for the view:

```
    <form name="pincodeForm" ng-submit="pinForm(pincodeForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        One time pin code: 
        <input type="text" name="content" ng-model="resultmessage.content" required data-countparens="" />
        <p ng-show="pincodeForm.content.$error.required && !pincodeForm.content.$pristine" class="help-block">Pin code is a required field.</p>     
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="pincodeForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Variable declaration at the top of the controller code includes the following, though some of the variables have had their values changed by running code:

```
$scope.credentials = {};
$scope.weblead = {type:"weblead", firstname: 'cuff', lastname: 'link', organization: "shirt", emailaddress: 'cuff@shirt.com'};
$scope.leadresult = "blank";
$scope.processStep = "start";
$scope.uname = "blank";
$scope.wleadid = "initial blank value";
$scope.existing = "blank";
```

Comment: what does `data-countparens` do? Have you tried removing it?

Comment: @charlietfl Removing `data-countparens` did not solve the problem.  And playing with the code reveals that anything that contains `$scope.resultmessage....` causes the problem.

Comment: Try adding an empty object in controller for that `$scope.resultmessage={}` . Not sure it will help but if there are any child scopes between form and controller it would. I've done lots of angular forms...never seen anything like this

Comment: I would try what charlietfl recommends and create an empty object. If that doesn't work we may need you to provide more code.

Comment: @charlietfl Declaring an empty `$scope.resultmessage={}` resolved the immediate problem.  If you want to submit it as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.  But how do I check for something like this myself in the future, besides simply always declaring new empty objects?  It feels like flying blind without a real IDE.

Comment: Browser freezes are quite rare unless you end up with infinite loop somehow. Almost always clues in dev tools except in a freeze. really no idea what would have caused one here without seeing more of the code